# Displaying an HTML table from a Django view in another template

Tags: python, html, django, pandas

So I have a Django view that allows for users to upload a file with data to be graphed via a Pandas dataframe. The graph is then created in a separate view which is referenced within the original file upload view via an image tag. This works perfectly.

Now I would also like to display the data in a table format next to the image of the graph. I'm using Panda's built in `dataframe.to_html()` to create the table in a separate view that will also be referenced within the file upload view.

I have the table generated correctly and can be seen at the URL specified for the table. I'm running into an error when I try to reference that URL from within my file upload template.

The error is:

`Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html`

I discovered that this is due to the fact that my file upload template has this line:

```
<img src="{% url 'html_graph' %}" />
```

since the view is returning an `HttpResponse` with a `content_type` of `text/html`.

**Is there a way to reference that HTML table view from within my file upload template that doesn't use the image tag since the table is HTML rather than an image?**

## Solution

Here is my working implementation:

```
html_table = df.to_html(index=False)
return render_to_response('myapp/my_template.html', {'html_table': html_table}, RequestContext(request))
```

I then reference that `html_table` in my template like:

```
<div>
 {{ html_graph | safe }}
</div>
```

**Edit**

*A correction in the template code:*

```
<div>
 {{ html_table | safe }}
</div>
```

Comment: That definitely works but I was hoping that there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. Thanks for the suggestion though @Filly.

Comment: Hi, so how do you go about exactly using the to_html method within a django template? When I try placing my to_html variable within {{ variable }} in the template, it just shows me the html string when I open the page up.

Comment: @KidSudi see the edit I made to my question. Hope it helps.

Comment: @alacy, Why not separate your answer/solution from your question? Kind of answering your own question.

Answer (score 3):

To work over it you can do one of the following listed below:

1. Use `<pre>` tag this way all the escaped characters like `&lt; &gt;` etc will be rendered as it is can be done as:

`<pre>
  {{ html_table }}
</pre>`

2. Use the `autoescape` filter available in django builtins can be done as:

`{% autoescape off %}
   {{ html_table }}
{% endautoescape %}`

The second option is better as it is given by django and only the developer has the authority over it.