# Cannot see the bottom part of html page in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas

I visualized pandas dataframe into html template in Django referring to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512261/displaying-an-html-table-from-a-django-view-in-another-template).
However, the bottom part of table cannot be seen as below image.(cannot scroll down)

[image]
Does anyone know what is causing this problem and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code. Could very well be an HTML/CSS issue -- Try taking the source and running it through an HTML validator.

Comment: I think that the problem is your footer. Try giving a margin bottom to that table.

Comment: It worked by setting margin bottom to the table!